# Accessing Azure Virtual Machine via RDP for the first time, stops at a command prompt

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've created a virtual machine using all the defaults and when once it's up and running, I try to access it via RDP.   I connect okay, the initial user setup screens pop up and then disappear as you'd expect, but one of the command prompt boxes stays open at the directory

`c:\users\theusername`

and nothing else happens.    I can type into the box here, with all the DOS commands, but can get no further.   Typing `exit` closes the command prompt and then I'm stuck with a black screen that just sits there.

I've tried restarting the VM via the Azure portal, I've trying deleting and creating new VMs with various settings all with the same result.

I'm wondering if there's something wrong with the account, but can't see anything that's obvious and Google's been no help.   Any ideas how to get a VM to start up properly to the desktop?

Comment: Which image do you use to create the VM? And what steps you follow?

Comment: The standard "Windows server, version 1709" with all the default settings.

I've used the same process/options on another Azure account and that worked fine.

Comment: And I've tried different size VMs, currently trying B2s

Comment: 2012 R2 SP1, 2016 Datacentre work, so it might be some interaction between the 1709 versions and the account???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Server  1709 are based on the Server Core installation option, that's why you get on boot the command prompt box.

[Windows Server version 1709](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/whats-new-in-windows-server-1709)

Comment: So, avoid them if you're as clueless about what to do with it as I apparently am?

Comment: Yes, if you don't have experience handling windows with commands, you should try another version.